# How to get DOM element id with OnClick inside map fuction in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs, onclick

I'm trying to get the DOM element id to change the background of a `<td>`. I'm printing a calendar with a map function from an array called from an outer function and adding an onclick function to each loop. But when I click the `<td>` I get the last id from that row. 
In the alert function, I get the value of the last day from the row

Any suggestions?

[Calendar Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcyI0.png)
This is my code:

```
cols = new Array(7).fill(0).map((zero, arrayCounter) => {
  if ((i === 0 && arrayCounter < weekDay) || numberDays < counterDay + 1) {
    return (
      <td id={arrayCounter} key={arrayCounter}>
        &nbsp;
      </td>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      counterDay++,
      (
        <td
          id={this.state.month + counterDay}
          key={this.state.month + counterDay}
          onClick={() => this.handleDays(actualRow, counterDay)}
        >
          {counterDay}
        </td>
      )
    );
  }
});

// When press a day
handleDays = (actualRow, counterDay) => {
  alert(actualRow + "-" + counterDay);
};
```

Comment: where do you initialize `actualRow` and `counterDay`?

Comment: above...  I just put this part of the code...

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that `actualRow` and `counterDay` variables are not saved for every individual row, they are pointing to the cycle variables and at the end of cycle they will always be equal to the values of last cycle.

What you can do is save values for every row in closure.

For example, you can rewrite your `handleDays` function to something like

```
handleDays = (actualRow, counterDay) => () => {
  alert(actualRow + "-" + counterDay);
};
```

And call us it in the `<td />` like

```js
<td
  id={this.state.month + counterDay}
  key={this.state.month + counterDay}
  onClick={this.handleDays(actualRow, counterDay)}
>
    {counterDay}
</td>
```

So, this construction will call `handleDays` with `actualRow` and `counterDay` variables on every cycle and return new function with variables saved in the closure.

You can read how the closer works in details here https://javascript.info/closure